# SQL: How to use conditions AND and OR in Sql

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have table with the following value

```
docid dcname doctitle 
1      **aa   **aaa01-01 
2      aa**   aafddg-02**
3      a**a   asds***90-05
4      abcd   abcd-06.
```

Now in this table i want to filter the "Doctitles" values beginning and ending with **

my result should be

```
dcid docname doctitle
3    a**a    asds***90-05
4    abcd    abcd-06
```

i am using the below query but the result obtained is only Doctitles with ** in the middle

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE     doctitle NOT LIKE '**%'
       AND doctitle NOT LIKE '%**'
       AND doctitle LIKE '%**%'
```

this gives me only below result
dcid docname doctitle
3    a**a    asds***90-05

Need help on this .

Comment: you want "Doctitles" values beginning and ending with **??? or Without **?

Answer (score 0):

Try without `and doctitle like '%**%'`
Your query should look `select * from table1 where doctitle not like '**%' and doctitle not like '%**'`

Another solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE LEFT(doctitle,2) != '**' AND RIGHT(doctitle,2) != '**'
```

Comment: but this query returns me values without any ** in doctiltes i want the doctitles that also contains "aa**09_01"

Comment: i added another solution to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options

```
select * from table1 where doctitle like '**%' and doctitle like '%**'
```

or

```
select * from table1 where doctitle like '**%'
UNION
select * from table1 where doctitle like '%**'
```

For more details refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it worked -

```
select * from 
(
select 
1    docid ,  '**aa' dcname  ,  '**aaa01-01' doctitle 
from dual
union all  
select 
2,      'aa**',   'aafddg-02**'
from dual
union all
select 
3 ,     'a**a' ,  'asds***90-05'
from dual
union all
select 
4  ,    'abcd'  , 'abcd-06.'
from dual
)
where doctitle not like '**%' and doctitle not like '%**'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant you do **not** want `doctitle`s starting or ending with `**`, you just need to omit your last conditional:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  doctitle NOT LIKE '**%'
  AND  doctitle NOT LIKE '%**'
```

Comment: thanks alot this solution was easy and was working thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
WHERE   doctitle LIKE '%**%'
AND     docid  NOT IN (SELECT docid  FROM tabel1 WHERE doctitle NOT LIKE '**%' )
AND     docid  NOT IN (SELECT docid  FROM tabel1 WHERE doctitle NOT LIKE '%**' )
```

Comment: I am declaring loacal variable @filter= '_**' can we write it this way @filter= '_**' & '**_' answer would of great help

Comment: No, you will have to write it separately, like `@filter LIKE '_**' AND @filter LIKE '**'`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
  FROM table1
  WHERE doctitle NOT LIKE '**%'
  OR doctitle NOT LIKE '%**'